# Run script before running tests in cocoa unit test target

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, mocking

I'm currently testing an iOS app that communicates with an JSON API. I need to start a sinatra server before running the tests. The server works as a mock for the real API.

Is there any way to run a one line script like this one `ruby /path/to/server.rb` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go to "Mange Schemes" and select you scheme, then expand "Tests" and select "Pre-actions" and add a new run script:

[image]

Select "Provide build settings from:" [image]

I think the variable you are looking for is `${SRCROOT}`

Comment: Answers with pictures make me happy!

Comment: Do you know how i can have access to the ruby script? It's currently located under proyect_root/Tests/server.rb. Is there any environment variable that points to the root? 

Thanks

Comment: I've added another picture to make @Filip even happier!

Comment: I'm running `ruby ${SRCROOT}/Tests/server.rb` but had no luck. Any clue on what could it be happening?

Comment: What did you select in the "Provide build settings from" dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Sebastian answer make sure to add & after your ruby command since without it sinatra will block your tests execution.

Also it's useful to take care about post-action where you need to kill the ruby process. 
Following example uses bundler and rackup to start sinatra.

Example for pre-action script:

```
exec > /tmp/tests-pre-actions.log 2>&1
source ~/.bash_profile

SERVER_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}"/"Server"
cd "$SERVER_PATH"
bundle exec rackup > /tmp/server.log 2>&1 &

#get the PID of the process
PID=$!

#save PID to file
echo $PID > /tmp/sinatra.pid
```

Example for post-action script:

```
exec > /tmp/tests-pre-actions.log 2>&1
source ~/.bash_profile

PID=$(</tmp/sinatra.pid)
echo "Sinatra server pid $PID"
kill -9 $PID
```

config.ru for rackup gem:

```
require './server'
trap('TERM') {Process.kill 'INT', Process.pid}
puts 'Run sinatra'
run Sinatra::Application
```